# RDP from linux to windows

Tags: linux, rdp, cve

Many users in our office use a Linux VM to connect to the office's RDP server to work remotely.

From March 2018 onwards a patch was progressively put out by Microsoft to address CVE-2018-0886, ultimately resulting in a final patch which no longer allows clients to connect without a specific flag being set.

Since this patch went out, those of us using linux to connect are no longer able to.

Previously most people used Remmina. I've tried KRDC. Both appear to be based on FreeRDP and fail to connect.

Is there some configuration value I'm failing to set when attempting to connect? Is there another RDP client for linux that works with the current version of CredSSP?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeRDP introduced support for the new NLA versions in the v2.0.0-rc2 ( https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/pull/4499/commits/8df96364f2d556d3dc34241de27fdb89c0d5bb42 )

It looks like Remmina also updated its FreeRDP library ( https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/1513 )

So depending on your distro it might be fixed by updating your packages. Otherwise you can always compile Remmina from source yourself.

Comment: Thanks eKKiM!

In the end I had to uninstall Remmina and install Remmina Next.

So, the problem was mine. As always.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change security settings of connection from "negotiate" to "TLS" in Remmina or you can try [VNC connect](https://www.realvnc.com/en/)

Comment: No dice on changing the handshake method, and I'm not in charge of infrastructure. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

I just got a new Windows Server 2019 server to build up and had to access it using Remmina on Ubuntu 18.04. Default RDP settings did not work.

I found the setting to allow it to connect: Edit -> Advanced -> Security -> choose NLA.

My Remmina version is: 1.2.0-rcgit-29